# How do I fetch OneToMany mappedBy when creating the child entity before the parent?

Tags: java, jpa

I have a model like this:

```
class Message {

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    // ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "messageId")
    private List<Value> values;
}

class Value {
    private UUID messageId;
}
```

The `Value` entities are being created in a JPA session, then, in another session, I create a `Message` in which I provide the `id` myself (which matches the `messageId` of existing `Value`).

After I have persisted the `Message`, when I try to call `getValues()` from it, I get `null`. What's the best way to solve this? Can I programmatically fetch the relation? Should I open another session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1: explicitly initialize child entities during parent entity creation**

Main idea of that solution is to create an additional method for loading `Value` entities by `messageId` in `ValueRepository` and use it explicitly to initialize values collection during `Message` entity creation.

Repository for loading Value entities:

```java
public interface ValueRepository extends JpaRepository<ValueEntity, Long> {    
    @Query("SELECT v FROM ValueEntity v WHERE v.messageId = :messageId")
    List<ValueEntity> findByMessageId(Long messageId);
}
```

Mesage creation and values collection initialization:

```java
    public Message createMessage() {
        Message message = new Message();
        message.setId(1L);
        message.setValues(valueRepository.findByMessageId(message.getId()));
        entityManager.persist(message);
        return message;
    }
```

**Solution 2: perform Flush and Refresh**

After`Message` persists operation you can perform [Flush operation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/flushing/Flushing.html), which will synchronize entity with database state, and then [Refresh operation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#refresh(java.lang.Object)), which will reread the state of the given entity.

```java
    public Message createMessage() {
        Message message = new Message();
        message.setId(1L);
        entityManager.persist(message);
        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.refresh(message);
        return message;
    }
```

I think **Solution 1** is preferable, it is better from a performance perspective because the flush operation can take additional time.

**UPDATE:**

In case of merge operation, use returned persisted entity for the refresh, instead of init object.

```java
    public Message createMessage() {
        Message message = new Message();
        message.setId(1L);
        Message persistedMessage = entityManager.merge(message);
        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.refresh(persistedMessage);
        return persistedMessage;
    }
```

Or better divide save and update operations

```java
   public Message saveOrUpdateMessage() {
        Message message =  entityManager.find(Message.class, 1L);
        if (message == null) {
            //handle new entity save
            message = new Message();
            message.setId(1L);
            entityManager.persist(message);
            entityManager.flush();
            entityManager.refresh(message);
        }
        //handle existing entity update
        ValueEntity valueEntity = new ValueEntity();
        valueEntity.setId(2L);
        valueEntity.setMessageId(message.getId());
        entityManager.persist(valueEntity);
        message.getValues().add(valueEntity);
        return message;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried the second one and I replaced `persist` with `merge` because I need a "save or update" behavior. I'm getting a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity not managed` exception on the `refresh` line. Not sure why... do you have an idea? I'm using hibernate as the JPA implementation and an injected `EntityManager` with the `@PersistenceContext` annotation

Comment: I updated the answer for the merge operation. Just use persisted entity for refresh operation which returned from merge method.